# How to dynamically remove space around text?

Tags: css, text

I would like to be able to remove the "space" at the top and the bottom of a text inside of a container.

[image]

The div must be as close as possible to the text inside.
This text is the result of a input and can be changed by the user.

I guess that I should work with the line-height, but how?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you set padding to the container `div`? If you have, then remove it, also what type of element is your text is it a `span` or a `p` etc. Remove the margin from this element.

Comment: This is not relevant to jQuery.

Comment: It is, since I've to update the font-size with js(jQuery). I will just apply the given solutions with it. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the title, I needed to "dynamically" remove the space around text.
In fact, every fonts have different structure and don't render in the same way on every browser...

I found a compromise for this :

```
.text { line-height: 70% }
```

As explained [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height), if we use a percentage, we could apply any font-size to our text, the line-height will always be the same.

I can change the font-size with jQuery, the line-height will always be properly applied to the text and to the surrounding element.

I dealt with a case function for every font to apply a different line-height. In my case, this is a working solution...

```
var fontFamily = $( "input" ).val(); // Here, the font-Size is defined dynamically by the user... It could be Arial, Verdana, Comic etc...
var lineHeight;

switch ( fontFamily ){

    case "Arial Black": // if the user has selected the arial black font...
        lineHeight = "70%"; // we define a line-height that will be correctly applied to the text
        break;
    case "Verdana":
        lineHeight = "78%";
        break;
    default:
        lineHeight = "66%";

}

$( ".text" ).css("line-height", lineHeight); // we apply the line-height to the text...
```

Note that the user can also change the font-size with another select element...

Hope this could help...

Answer (score 6):

Used to `line-height`

```
.some_css{
line-height: px; // according to your text size of design 
}
```

Comment: In my case, the font-size of the word can be changed by the user. So I have to get a new value for line-height when the font-size will change, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the CSS `padding` property to set space within the borders of the element:

```
padding:0;
```

Additionally as Terric has pointed out, if the child has a margin, remove it:

```
margin:0;
```

Comment: The margin and padding are not helpful at all in my case. I had to deal with the line-height to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

you can either use `padding: 0`' or try `line-height:px`

1. what padding do

> [image]

with zero padding

> [image]

2. and line height

> [image]

Comment: In my case the problem was the line-height. I've noticed that this parameter is related to the font-size and the font itself.
Look at my answer to understand how I managed to solve the issue.
Thanks for your help!